# Python script to remove all the txt files that match a condition from subdirectories without affecting the directory structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-processing

I am trying to write a python script that removes txt files that have less than "wordLimit" words, where "wordLimit" is a given number. The files should be removed from all the directories and subdirectories at a certain path. The directory structure should stay the same.

My version always prints "Error while deleting file"

```
import os, glob
wordLimit = 1000
directory = os.getcwd()

def shouldArticleBeRemoved(filepath, minWords):
    number = 0
    filename = os.path.basename(filepath)
    with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
        for line in f:
            words = line.split()
            number += len(words)
    if number < minWords:
        return True
    else: return False

def iterateCheckAndRemove():
    notRemoved = 0
    removed = 0
    fileList = glob.glob('C:/Users/HP/Desktop/Articles/*/*/*.txt', recursive=True)
    for filePath in fileList:
        try:
            if shouldArticleBeRemoved(filePath, wordLimit):
                os.remove(filePath)
                removed += 1
            else: notRemoved +=1
        except OSError:
            notRemoved +=1
            print("Error while deleting file")
    print(removed)

iterateCheckAndRemove()
```

Comment: can you paste the full error? Just print the error `except OSError as e` then `pint(e)`

Comment: The below error is repeated for all the articles.
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Article.txt'
The files exist at that path.

Comment: What would be an example of the directory structure not being the same; why/how would removing files change the structure of just the directories, which are not files?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It's much simpler:-

```
import os

def main():
    wordLimit = 1000
    for r, _, f in os.walk(r'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Articles'):
        for _f in f:
            apath = os.path.join(r, _f)
            _, ext = os.path.splitext(apath)
            if ext == '.txt':
                try:
                    rflag = False
                    with open(apath) as text:
                        if len(text.read().split()) < wordLimit:
                            rflag = True
                    if rflag:
                         os.remove(apath)
                         print(f'{apath} was deleted')
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f'Error while processing {apath} -> {e}')

        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you! Your script sees all the files but it always returns [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. 
I tried to end all the processes that involved python from the task manager but it stays the same.

Comment: This code works on macOS (Unix) because it's possible to remove a file while it's open (the deletion will occur once it's closed). I'll make a small change to the code which will continue to work on Unix type systems but may help on Windows. If that doesn't work then you must have something running that's got these files open.

Comment: It works perfectly with that change. Thank you!